# Two angularjs windows with different information

Tags: angularjs

I have an application with angularjs 1.5.3 that when a button is pressed opens a new window.

```
$window.open($state.href('catalog-detalleTicketMapa', {
    id: $localStorage.idRamdom
  }), 'window', 'height=700,width=700');
```

Everything is correct, the problem that if on the main page I navigate to another screen, it does the same in the auxiliary window

It is possible to avoid this behavior. I just need the auxiliary window to stay static.

Comment: A plunker would help, I am not sure I understand the problem. If no plunker, either you separate the variable part in an iframe and navigate only that or you replicate static part on the new window to match the previous one, if needed saving state of previous one instead init it again